# Set visible URL with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url-routing

Is there a way to set the displayed url of a page using Spring MVC ?
Let me be clearer with an example : I have the following controller :

```
@Controller
public class Display{
    @RequestMapping(value = "myPage")
    public ModelAndView display() {
        ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView(Uris.MY_PAGE);
        return result;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "myPage/revisited")
    public ModelAndView accountManagement() {
        ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView(Uris.ACCOUNT);
        return display();
    }
}
```

If I go on `myPage/Revisited`, I'll get the JSP associated to `myPage`. However, in my browser, the url will stay the same (`myPage/revisited`). How could I prevent that ?

Comment: using HttpServletResponse response -> response.sendRedirect(location) ? (I do not understand well the meaning of the accountManagement method)

Comment: I just tried, It redirects me to `/myPage/revisited/myPage`.

Comment: You have to search info about "spring MVC URL rewriting", it seems to be what you need

Comment: Indeed, I'll dig into it.

Comment: I made two controllers: one mapped as /test1 and the other as /test2:  /test2 controller do a redirect to /test1 and in my browser the url change to /test1 after i request /test2 (as it should be). I've the feeling I am missing something..

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = "test1")
 public String test1(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model, Locale locale) {

  
  return "view";

 }
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "test2")
 public void test2(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model, Locale locale) {

  
  response.sendRedirect("test1");

 }` this works

Comment: What if you change `@RequestMapping(value = "test2")` by  `@RequestMapping(value = "test1/test2")` ?

Comment: I get it now, that case better using this approach: `@RequestMapping(value = "test1/test2")
 public void test2(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model, Locale locale) throws IOException {
  response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/test1");
 }`so you can keep add logic into the controller if you need to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more precise on what sam said, you can use [UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/), the installation process is explained in the link, then set a rule in the file `urlrewrite.xml`:

```
 <rule  match-type="wildcard">
        <from>/myPage/revisited/redirect</from>         
        <to type="redirect">%{context-path}/myPage</to> 
</rule>
```

And in your controller, just use what Emanuele said, i.e. 
`response.sendRedirect("redirect");`